# button.click only executed with alert in front

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, mootools-events

First of all:
This page is for an online pharmacy.
We are using a small script to retrieve some data from insurance companies to ensure that a user actually has an insurance.

On one of our pages we have 2 text-fields and a button. The text field send a `.click()` to the button to retrieve some information, but only if they are both filled with the right type of data.
This Works.

To enhance the usability of our site we are creating a flow trough different pages. The page previously described is amongst them.
I'm sure that the required information is always in the 2 text-fields so I'm using JavaScript to send a `.click()` to the button. But somehow `$('ZK').click();` does not work, but `alert(); $('ZK').click();` does.

Is there any one that is able to explain to me why the first is not working and the second is? And perhaps also how I can fix this minor problem?

Is there something with the `.click()` not having an event or something?

Code inside this page: (not loaded indirectly)

text-field and button:

```
<INPUT onkeypress="return noenter()"  
       onkeydown="return isNumericKey(event)"  
 TYPE="TEXT"  
 class="ajaxsearch"  
 name="DOB" id="DOB"  
 value="<%=DOB%>"  
 MAXLENGTH="8"  
 style="width:60px;height:18px"  
 onkeyup="javascript:if ($(DOB).get('value').length==8 &&  
                         $(DOB).get('value')!='ddmmjjjj')
 {  
   var myFx=new Fx.Tween($(DOB));  
   myFx.set('color','#000066');  
   $('ZK').click();  
 } else {  
   var myFx=new Fx.Tween($(DOB));  
   myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');  
 };">  `

<INPUT url="?NC=<%=Rnd(Now)%>"  
 TYPE="BUTTON"  
 NAME="ZK" ID="ZK"  
 VALUE="Zoek mij"  
 class="button"  
 style="width:70px;height:22px">
```

The call script:

```
  if ($('DOB').get('value').length==8 
      && $('DOB').get('value')!='ddmmjjjj') 
  {
    var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB'));
    myFx.set('color', '#000066');
    //alert();
    $('ZK').click();
   } else {
     var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB'));
     myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');
   }
```

Ajax script & call:

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
    window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
      $('ZK').addEvent('click', function(event) { 
        event.stop(); 
        var req = new Request.HTML({ 
          method: 'post', 
          url: '../ajax/a_bsn.asp',
          data: {
            'BSN':$('BSN').get('value'), 
            'DOB':$('DOB').get('value'),
            'RequestType':'WWW',
            'RXID':'<%=GUID%>'
          }, 
          update: $('RES'),
          onRequest: function() {
            $('RES').innerHTML = '<img width="16px" height="16px" src="../images/spinner.gif"/>';
    }}).send(); 
  });

////////
<%  If (Len(BSN)=8 or Len(BSN)=9) and IsNumeric(BSN) and Len(DOB)=8 and IsNumeric(DOB) Then %>
if ($('BSN').get('value').length>7){
  var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('BSN'));
  myFx.set('color', '#000066');
} else {
  var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('BSN'));
  myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');
}
if ($('DOB').get('value').length==8 && $('DOB').get('value')!='ddmmjjjj'){
  var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB'));
  myFx.set('color', '#000066');
  // var $zk = $('ZK'); console.log($zk); $zk.click();
  // alert('Uw gegevens worden ingevuld.');
  setTimeout("$('ZK').click();",1);
  //$('ZK').click();
} else {
  var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB'));
  myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');
}
<%  End If %>
////////
});
</script>
```

Div affected by Ajax

```
<DIV id="RES">      
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" ID="PNAAM" onkeypress="return noenter()"  NAME="PNAAM" VALUE="<%=PNAAM%>" class="text_inv" style="width:375px">
</div>
```

Comment: @raina77ow 
This works. The text-fields contain the exact same code and work.  
Not loaded dynamically and also some extra code posted in the question.

Comment: Ok... can you replace this `alert` call with these lines: `var $zk = $('ZK'); console.log($zk); $zk.click();` ?

Comment: @raina77ow Returns _Logboek: [object HTMLInputElement]_

Comment: Wait a minute. What should happen after `$zk.click()`? Some event handler called, or just a form submitted?

Comment: Ajax call to insert the persons name in a span and fill a hidden field so the system knows the user has insurance.

One of my not-ICT-related colleagues (customer service) came up with an interesting idea: Time-out. This also seems to work: `setTimeout("$('ZK').click();",1);`

I would still like to know where the problem actually came from.

Comment: Could you show here the code of this ajax caller instead? You can also add some `console.log` to its beginning - just to make sure that it's not fired (or is fired, actually).

Comment: Ok, got it, but some code still has to link the 'click' event and this `req` variable; it should be inside a function (attached as 'click' handler for 'ZK') or something, right?

Comment: @raina77ow I posted pretty much all the code used by this part of the page. But that is done just before the code the question is about is executed. Although javascript is single-threaded only, it seems to try and ask for the .click() before it is actually attached to ZK. And just 1ms later is is attached and can be executed.

Comment: One last question: will it work the same if you move the whole block that I marked with '////' in your question right after `}}).send();` line?

Comment: right after it? No, that is still the onclick. in the next one it actually already was, but made a mistake coping it to this page. But that also doesn't work. One more and the element does not even exist because it fires tight away then.
But I get your thought and it should work, but it doesn't and that just frustrates me. I'll just leave it with the time-out of 1ms and let our lead-programmer take a look at it when he is back from holiday. He's better with JavaScript than me. I'll post his findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our lead-programmer (who originally made the page somewhere around 8 years ago) thought it might be better to move all logic into functions. That way they could be triggered easier in other parts of code if necessary. We also removed all the (old) inline scripts.

In this solution some parts of the other answers were used. I'd like to thank al the other answerers and commenters for their help.

The top part of the code looks like this now (tested and working stable across browsers):

```
    function updateName(){
        if (document.id('BSN').get('value').length>7 && document.id('DOB').get('value').length==8 && document.id('DOB').get('value')!='ddmmjjjj'){
            var req = new Request.HTML({
                method: 'post',
                url: '../ajax/a_bsn.asp',
                data:{'BSN':document.id('BSN').get('value'),'DOB':document.id('DOB').get('value'),'RequestType':'WWW','RXID':'<%=GUID%>'},
                update: document.id('RES'),
                onRequest: function() {
                    document.id('RES').innerHTML = '<img width="16px" height="16px" src="../images/spinner.gif"/>';
                }
            }).send();
        }
    }
    function checkBSN(){
        if (document.id('BSN').get('value').length>7){
            var myFx=new Fx.Tween(document.id('BSN'));
            myFx.set('color', '#000066');
            updateName();
        } else {
            var myFx=new Fx.Tween(document.id('BSN'));
            myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');
        }
    }
    function checkDOB(){
        if (document.id('DOB').get('value').length==8 && document.id('DOB').get('value')!='ddmmjjjj'){
            var myFx=new Fx.Tween(document.id('DOB'));
            myFx.set('color', '#000066');
            updateName();
        } else {
            var myFx=new Fx.Tween(document.id('DOB'));
            myFx.set('color', '#cc0000');
        }
    }
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        document.id('ZK').addEvent('click', function(event) {
            event.stop && event.stop();
            updateName();
        });
        document.id('BSN').addEvent('keyup', function(event) {
            event.stop && event.stop();
            updateName();
        });
        document.id('DOB').addEvent('keyup', function(event) {
            event.stop && event.stop();
            updateName();
        });
    <%  If (Len(BSN)=8 or Len(BSN)=9) and IsNumeric(BSN) and Len(DOB)=8 and IsNumeric(DOB) Then %>
        updateName();
    <%  End If %>
    });
```

Comment: `$$('#ZK,#BSN,#DOB').addEvent('click', updateName);` and `function updateName(event) { event && event.stop && event.stop(); ... }` - find patterns and code to them.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, among other errors, you have a previous statement which is not ended with a semicolon. Try removing the `alert()` and leaving the `;` to test. Also, if you haven't, check your console as you should see *at least* 1 error.

Comment: Nice tip about the console, but somehow I doubt ASI might be confused by `$` symbol. But then again, the real code wasn't given to us obviously.

Comment: Leaving just the `;` did not do anything, the console is quite emtpy about this part. Does have some css warnings.

Answer (score 0):

After your edits my initial answer stopped making sense.

**EDIT :**

Your click handler and ajax call are wrapped in a `domready` event handler function. Your "call script" should also be in domready. According to your latest edits the `domready` handler is closed just before the ASP tag `<%`

This is what you posted:

```
        }).send();  // --this is the end of ajax
    }); // -- this is the end of the click handler
}); // -- this is the end of domready
<%  If (Len(BSN)=8
```

So your call script:

```
if ($('DOB').get('value').length==8 && $('DOB').get('value')!='ddmmjjjj') {
    var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB')); myFx.set('color', '#000066');
    //alert();
    $('ZK').click();
} else { var myFx=new Fx.Tween($('DOB')); myFx.set('color', '#cc0000'); }
```

needs to go inside `domready` **after you have attached the click handler**:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    // Let's attach the click handler:
    $('ZK').addEvent('click', function(event) {...do the ajax here etc...});

   // the "call script" needs to be here

});
```

You need to wait for the document structure to load.

By the way, it would help if you stopped moving the code around in your question - just post what you are currently using.

Comment: That already happens. Please take a careful look at the last part of the code, but thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: Right, after your edits my answer doesn't make too much sense. I'll try to amend.

Answer (score 0):

reuse your functions, selectors and variables...

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var ZK = $('ZK');
    ZK.addEvent('click', function(event) { 
        // make event safe and reusable via software call
        event.stop && event.stop(); // don't call stop if not a real event.

        // logic here


    });

    $('DOB').addEvent('keyup', function() {
        // this == DOB
        var value = this.get('value'); // get it once.

        if (value.length && value.length === 8 && value !== 'ddmmjjjj') {
            // do not call click! we can now fireEvent
            ZK.fireEvent('click'); 
        }
    });
});
```

don't use inline js. don't rely on $, use `document.id` instead for mootools 1.2.4+

to recap, do not go to the dom to do a synthetic `.click()` - its not the most reliable and you don't need to.